# pidstat -u -I shows cpu usage 385%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, top

I have a guest running in qemu doing linux kernel compilation. From host, I am watching its usage with below command

pidstat 4 -p pid_of_process -u -I

-I flag should average out for all number of processors, according to man page. Then how can usage go beyond 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

`pid 4 -p -u -I` does not work on my distro, but `pid 4 -p ALL -u -I` does. I've never seen over 100% though, how does it compare with the `uptime` numbers in this case? In addition, what is the result of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep process`?